# initclt not seeing init script in Ubuntu 12 64bit

Tags: upstart, services, scripts, init.d

I created an init script in LSB format, and copied it to the /etc/init.d directory. I can manually start, stop, status the service and all works fine.
I then try to set the service to auto stop/start with runlevels by doing:

```
update-rc.d service defaults
```

and I see warnings like:

> update-rc.d: warning: xxx start runlevel arguments (none) do not match
>   lsb default-Start values (3 4 5).

and  initctl list" does not show my service. Is there a step I need to do to make this service register or appear properly? (I know on RedHat it's "chkconfig --add xxx) but I don't know Ubuntu well enough.

Comment: `update-rc.d service defaults`, with an **s** at the end.

Comment: I fixed that typo.  Confirmed that result is the same, "initclt list" still does not show my service (but I do see the S symlink in the /etc/rc3.d/ directory for my service).  Am I perhaps misunderstanding which initctl list should show?

Comment: See my answer^^

Answer (score 1):

`initctl` is part of Uubuntu's upstart mechanism. `initctl list` only shows you the status of upstart-jobs. Your script is indeed is a SysV init script.

To list the status of SysV init script use this command:

```
service --status-all
```

Your service should be listed there.

---

To create links in the `/etc/rcN` folders use the following command:

```
update-rc.d your_init_script defaults
```

From the manpage of `update-rc.d`:

> If defaults is used then update-rc.d will make links to start the
>   service in runlevels 2345 and to  stop  the service in runlevels 016.

Comment: OK I'm getting it now.  So why this error then: update-rc.d: warning: xxx start runlevel arguments (none) do not match lsb default-Start values (3 4 5).  Where is it getting "(none)" from?  My scripts has default start values of 3 4 5.

Comment: Because the lsb-headers of your script say 3 4 5 but `defaults` means add the scripts to **2** 3 4 5.

Comment: Then how can I add init script?  (If I remove the word defaults I get errors)

Comment: Use this command:  `update-rc.d your_service start 20 3 4 5 . stop 20 0 1 6 .`. This means, start the service in runlevels 2, 3 & 4 and stop the service in runlevels 0, 1 & 6. 20 is the order (see the `/etc/rc*/` dirs).